# Extremely stupid FreeBSD mistake

Tags: ssh, freebsd

I accidently did a echo "" > /etc/rc.conf on my box and I locked my self out completely stupidly tring to get the rc.conf back then rebooted making my self locked out.

Answer (score 6):

You've got two options:

1. Try booting to single user mode.  [This](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-freebsd-reset-recover-root-password.html) claims to tell you how, but I'm not sure how much of that behavior depends on rc.conf, so you may have to...
2. Boot a [rescue CD](http://www.paultastic.com/blogs/index.php?title=freebsd_rescue_cd&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1). Ideally a freeBSD one that you can copy the rc.conf off of and onto your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Single user mode doesn't use rc.conf at all.

You can get into SU mode by rebooting and waiting until the loader comes up - that shows you the full screen ASCII display with a count down timer - and press 4.

If the bold white kernel text appears before you press 4 you missed it.